# how to use ggplot to map data with two factors?

Tags: r, ggplot2, anova

```
df <- data.frame(mean_rt = c(270.4860, 377.4106, 274.7234, 371.7627),  sd_rt = c(33.66426, 53.43924, 35.04275, 51.0443), block = c(1, 1, 2, 2), task = c(1, 2, 1, 2))
```

Above is a summary table I made for my data. I'm trying to map it onto a line graph. Here's a picture to show you what I want it to look like:

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPxEr.png)

Basically, I want the block variable on the x axis and the rt variable on the y axis with error bars.

To achieve this, I wrote the following code:

```
ggplot(summary_rt, aes(block, mean_rt, color = task)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean_rt-sd_rt, ymax=mean_rt+sd_rt))
```

And here's what I ended up with:
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsQij.png)

How do I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to treat `block` and `task` as factors. Since the columns in the data frame are numeric, `ggplot2` is using them as continuous variables. You could `mutate()` them to coerce the types to character or factor, or call `factor()` in your plot function like:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


df %>%
  mutate(across(c(block, task), factor)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(block, mean_rt, color = task, group = task)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean_rt-sd_rt,
                    ymax = mean_rt+sd_rt),
                width = 0.2) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = 'block',
       color = 'task')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution! Here are a couple of follow up questions:
(1) How to make the error bars smaller? (2) Is it possible to connect the green dot to the other green dot (same goes for the orange dots)?

Comment: `geom_errorbar` has a `width` argument you can use to customize the width of the bars. `linewidth` could also be changed to adjust the thickness of the lines themselves. I've edited my answer with a change to the aesthetics mapping to connect the blocks differently.